# expectation larger than limsup for sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's say we are given a sequence of real-valued random variables, $X_n, n\geq1$, subject to the following conditions:

a) $X_n\geq0$ P-a.s.

b) $\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n=C>0$ P-a.s., where C is a constant. In fact, we can assume that any given $c\leq C$ is a limit point of $X_n$ with probability either 0 or 1.

c) $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\geq C$ for all $n\geq 1$, although this expectation might be infinite.

Can we deduce that $X_n$, in fact, converges to $C$ P-a.s. as $n\to\infty$? Or, equivalently, is it possible for this sequence to have a limit inferior strictly smaller than C?

Intuitively, it appears to me that such a sequence should in fact converge, but I can't seem to find a good line of argument for that (and of course, I just might be wrong and simply did not see a counterexample).

A bit of background: This question originated from thinking about some asymptotic properties of stochastic processes, so the conditions above are what I could extract so far.

Comment: No, by variation of standard examples.  Fix $C>0$. You can make the $E[X_n]\geq C+1$ condition hold for all $n$ by defining $X_n$ to take large values for all $n \leq G$ for $G$ a geometric random variable.  Then make $X_n$ (surely) oscillate between $0$ and $C$ for all $n>G$. Can you construct such an example?

Comment: @Michael: Really good point, I missed this idea completely. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome.  If you feel so inclined,  you can construct the specific example and post it as an answer to this question, then vote that as best (it is standard to answer your own question if you come to a conclusion later, possibly based on hints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a construction of an explicit example based on Michael's idea: Let $G$ be a geometrically distributed random variable with parameter $p=1/2$. Define 
$$ X_n:=\begin{cases}2^nC, &\text{ for } n\leq G\\
  0, &\text{ for } n>G\ \text{even}\\
  C, &\text{ for } n>G\ \text{odd} \end{cases}$$
Conditions a) and b) are satisfied by construction, the sequence does not converge, and for c), we calculate
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_n]\geq 2^nC\cdot\mathbb{P}[G\geq n]=2^nC\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}=C\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{2^k}=2C.$$